# Prove using superposition that an LTI system is linear

Tags: continuous-signals

Given an LTI system of the form:

$$ \frac{d}{dt}{x}(t) = {A} {x}(t) \ + \ {B} {u}(t) $$

where ${x}(t)$ is the state variable, ${u}(t)$ an input and ${A}$ and ${B}$ constants, how does one show, by superposition, that the system is linear? I've searched and searched and tried to do it myself and I am unable to do so. Seems more difficult that it seems. Most books seem to gloss over the fact.

Comment: Most people expand _LTI_ when they encounter the acronym in system theory as _linear time-invariant_ and a linear system is _by definition_ one that satisfies the superposition property. So, in some sense, there is _nothing_ to prove.

Comment: i am editing the math in all of this to use proper matrix/vector notation that you get with state-variable system description.

Comment: with an LTI system represented in the general state-variable form, you need also worry about **controllability**.  if the system is not completely controllable, there are states (or some "mode" or linear combination of states) that are, effectively, not hooked up to the input $\mathbf{u}(t)$. now, that said, **if** the system is completely controllable, then every state in $\mathbf{x}(t)$ can be represented as the sum of components of that state that are driven by each input in $\mathbf{u}(t)$. so then first break it down to a single-input single-output question. and i'll try to answer that.

Comment: or is this already a single-input, single-output question?  then it's a **specific** first-order system.  perhaps i have acted prematurely in editing the question.

Comment: Either, matrix or scalar, same problem. A have to disagree with Sarwate's comment however. It can't be by definition otherwise I could state by definition, that y = x^2 is linear. A proof of linearity is required so that all the theorems than can be derived for LTI systems are valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume the system has the initial condition $x(0) = 0$, as otherwise the system isn't linear.

Suppose the input $u_1(t)$ yields the output $x_1(t)$ and the input $u_2(t)$ yields the output $x_2(t)$.

We need to prove that the input $u(t) = \alpha u_1(t)+\beta u_2(t)$ yields the output $x(t) = \alpha x_1(t) + \beta x_2(t)$ for any scalars $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

The given input and output pairs must satisfy the differential equation and the initial condition. Hence, $x_1'(t) = Ax_1(t)+Bu_1(t)$ and $x_2'(t) = Ax_2(t)+Bu_2(t)$ for all times $t$ and $x_1(0) = x_2(0) = 0$.

Now, add $\alpha$ times the first equation to $\beta$ times the second equation to get: $\alpha x_1'(t) + \beta x_2'(t) = \alpha(Ax_1(t)+Bu_1(t)) + \beta(Ax_2(t)+Bu_2(t))$

Then, rearrange stuff to get:

$\dfrac{d}{dt}[\alpha x_1(t) + \beta x_2(t)] = A(\alpha x_1(t)+\beta x_2(t)) + B(\alpha u_1(t)+\beta u_2(t))$

$x'(t) = Ax(t)+Bu(t)$

Also, we have $x(0) = \alpha x_1(0)+\beta x_2(0) = \alpha \cdot 0 + \beta \cdot 0 = 0$.

Thus, the signals $u(t) = \alpha u_1(t)+\beta u_2(t)$ and $x(t) = \alpha x_1(t) + \beta x_2(t)$ satisfy the differential equation and the initial condition. Hence, the input $u(t) = \alpha u_1(t)+\beta u_2(t)$ yields the output $x(t) = \alpha x_1(t) + \beta x_2(t)$ for any inputs $u_1(t)$ and $u_2(t)$ and any scalars $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Therefore, the system is linear, as desired.

Comment: Many thanks. I assumed that the initial conditions could be  x(0) <> 0 hence my trouble in showing linearity. I assume then that many of the theorems in LTI theory that rely on linearity must make the same assumption that x(0) = 0, for example convolution?

Comment: *"I'm going to assume the system has the initial condition $x(0)=0$, as otherwise the system isn't linear. "*  i have to disagree with this, because $x(0)$ can simply be defined as $$ x(0) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{0} u(\tau) h(-\tau) d\tau $$ and, even if $x(0) \ne 0$, if superposition applies, it's still linear.

Comment: Oh right, the system doesn't necessarily have to start operating at $t = 0$ or any particular finite starting time. If that is the case, just ignore everything regarding initial conditions.

Answer (score 1):

here is why, for a simple single-input, single-output (SISO) system, with no hidden states (i.e. completely controllable and completely observable), if superposition is known to be a valid property (called ["additivity"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_function) by the math guys, you can also show that the scaling property (called ["homogeneous of degree 1"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function#Linear_functions) by the math guys) of linearity is also the case for real and rational scalers.

you need to do a little hand-waving regarding continuity to extend this to the irrational scalers, because you can always get arbitrarily close to any irrational number with a rational one.

so let's say that $T\{ \cdot \}$ is something that transforms an input $x(t)$ into an output $y(t)$

$$ y(t) = T\{ x(t) \} $$

and this is true for all possible $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$:

$$ T\{ x_1(t) + x_2(t) \} = T\{ x_1(t) \} + T\{ x_2(t) \} $$

now suppose $x_2(t) = x_1(t) = x(t)$

$$ T\{ x(t) + x(t) \} = T\{ x(t) \} + T\{ x(t) \} $$

or

$$ T\{ 2 \ x(t) \} = 2 \ T\{ x(t) \} $$

so you've just proved the linear scaling property for the real scaler $2$.  how would you go about proving it for $3$?  and then $4$?  and then for *any* positive integer $N$?  (it's called "proof by induction" and it's easy.)

so we're able to easily prove that superposition implies linear scaling for positive integers (and easily extended to all real integers):

$$ T\{ N \ x(t) \} = N \ T\{ x(t) \} \quad \quad N \in \mathbb{Z} $$

now how about this:

$$ T\left\{ \frac{1}{M} \ x(t) \right\} = ?? \quad \quad M \in \mathbb{Z} $$

define

$$ x_M(t) \triangleq \frac{1}{M} \ x(t) $$

so we know that

$$ T\left\{ M \ x_M(t) \right\} = M \ T\left\{ x_M(t) \right\} \quad \quad M \in \mathbb{Z} $$

but we also know that

$$ T\left\{ x_M(t) \right\} = T\left\{\frac{1}{M} \ x(t) \right\} $$

and

$$ T\left\{ M \ x_M(t) \right\} = T\left\{M \ \frac{1}{M} \ x(t) \right\} = T\{ x(t) \} $$

then we know that

$$ T\left\{ M \ x_M(t) \right\} = T\{ x(t) \} = M \ T\left\{ \frac{1}{M} \ x(t) \right\} \quad \quad M \in \mathbb{Z} $$

and

$$ T\left\{ \frac{1}{M} \ x(t) \right\} = \frac{1}{M} \ T\{ x(t) \} \quad \quad M \in \mathbb{Z} $$

so now we proved linear scaling for any reciprocal of an integer.  sohow do you think we might do this form the general rational scaler $\frac{N}{M}$ where $N,M \in \mathbb{Z}$?  i don't think it takes Einstein to see that

$$ T\left\{ \frac{N}{M} \ x(t) \right\} = \frac{N}{M} \ T\{ x(t) \} \quad \quad N,M \in \mathbb{Z} $$

so, just given superposition

$$ T\{ x_1(t) + x_2(t) \} = T\{ x_1(t) \} + T\{ x_2(t) \} $$

we know that scaling is also true

$$ T\{ \alpha x \} = \alpha \ T\{ x(t) \}  \quad \quad \alpha = \frac{N}{M} \quad N,M \in \mathbb{Z}$$

and we know that

$$ T\left\{ \sum\limits_{i} \alpha_i x_i(t) \right\} = \sum\limits_{i} \alpha_i T \{ x_i(t) \} $$

where all $\alpha_i$ are rational.  for the irrational $\alpha$, one must make an additional (and reasonable) assumption about the transform mapping $T\{\cdot\}$, that it is continuous, so that as rational $\alpha$ gets closer and closer to a irrational target (and changes very little), the behavior of $T\{\cdot\}$ will also change very little.  i'm not gonna deal with that now.

but, from just a little thinking, it's clear that, at least for real and rational scalers, superposition implies linear scaling and then the whole of linearity in general.  (says nothing about time-invariance, which is a whole 'nother property.)